# django ValidationError in admin save_model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Models.py

```
class user(AbstractUser):
    salary_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

Admin.py

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if obj.salary_number == None:
        raise ValidationError("ERROR salary number!")
    ....
    obj.save()
```

I'm trying to show error for user if they forget to fill salary number, but I got error ValidationError at /admin/information/user/add/. How can I fixed that?

I have a reason to not set salary_number null & blank = False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to make a small `ModelForm`:

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class UserModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    def clean_salary_number(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['salary_number']
        if data is None:
            raise ValidationError('ERROR salary number!')
        return data
```

and then plug this in in the `ModelAdmin`:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # …
    form = UserModelForm
```